# How can I send multiple select boxes values with same name attribute in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

these are two select boxes with same name can any one guide mehow can I pass two select boxes values as one one single array

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="servicetypes[]" id="servicetypes" class="form-control">
<option value="">-- Choose Service Areas --</option>
<option value="1">all over `enter code here`Andhrapredesh</option>
<option value="11">asia</option>
<option value="12">North-South America</option>
</select>
<select multiple="multiple" name="servicetypes[]" id="servicetypes" class="form-control">`enter code here`
 <option value="">-- Choose Service Areas --</option>
 <option value="1">all over Andhrapredesh</option>
 <option value="11">asia</option>
 <option value="12">North-South America</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: What's the use of having two `select`s with the same name? Your first `select` already is a multi-select?!

Comment: you can't - one would override the other...

Comment: If you want to have some nice differentation inside your select maybe you could use select2 for that: [example here](https://select2.org/selections)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you.

### Source code

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="servicetypes[]"]', function(){
  
        var selectedValues = {};
        $('select[name="servicetypes[]"]').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).children("option").filter(":selected").text();
            var value = $(this).val();
            selectedValues[text] = value;

        });

        var textValue = $('#servicetypesArray').val(selectedValues);
     
      alert(JSON.stringify(selectedValues, null, 4));

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple" name="servicetypes[]" id="servicetypes" class="form-control">
    <option value="">-- Choose Service Areas --</option>
    <option value="1">all over Andhrapredesh</option>
    <option value="11">asia</option>
    <option value="12">North-South America</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple="multiple" name="servicetypes[]" id="servicetypes" class="form-control">`enter code here`
     <option value="">-- Choose Service Areas --</option>
     <option value="1">all over Andhrapredesh</option>
     <option value="11">asia</option>
     <option value="12">North-South America</option>
     </select>

    <input type="text" id="servicetypesArray" name="data[servicetypes][]" value="" hidden/>
```

**You will have your values in a multidimensional array named 'servicetypes'**

*Here is a [CODEPEN Demo](https://codepen.io/athullive/pen/XYLZeE)*

Answer (score 0):

Always use different name or id for two different input/select in a form. When you post the form, you will get values in array format. And since you have used the same name, all the selected values from the both select box will be in the same name array called servicetypes[].